# webcomponent basic (no polymer, etc..): simple example 'hello world', why does it need a server?

Tags: web-component, custom-element, html5-import

i'm new on webcomponent, i read some guides, but i really can't figured out how to build a simple webcomponent, on latest chrome 56 (so, no polyfill needed). I want to use it without external libraries (no polymer, etc). The only simple example i found is this (https://github.com/webcomponents/hello-world-element) but i don't understand why it needs a server (polyserve) to see the index.html working. It's only client-side, like Angular2. 
Thanks

Comment: Seems you’re likely to get a better answer if you post this question at https://github.com/webcomponents/hello-world-element/issues

Comment: Note that `rel-import` have been deprecated since. Web-compoents that were using them (like https://github.com/Polight/lego/) had to be re-written and imported in js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs a server because it makes use of `<link rel="import">` HTML element which requires a server for security reasons.

This `<link>` loads external resources that could be malicious, much more than a simple CCS stylesheet loaded with `<link rel="stylesheet">`.

---

Here is a simple example that doesn't need a server to run:

```js
customElements.define( 'hello-world', class extends HTMLElement 
{
  connectedCallback() {
     console.log( 'connected' )
     this.innerHTML = 'Hello, World!'
  }
} )
```

```html
<hello-world></hello-world>
```

Comment: OK thanks! Now my problem is "how can i make it works on a cordova-phonegap project without a server?" but it's OT, i'll searching about. Thanks

Comment: You could be able to use <link rel=import> in a cordova-app (wich actually embeds its own server). You can also import Javascript Web Component files with <script> instead of HTML file with <link rel=import>

Comment: you should read http://stackoverflow.com/q/41539717/4600982 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/a/25800991/4600982

Comment: Thanks! I just needed the simplest possible example to get started :)